# Как я могу получить метаданные фотографии с помощью python

Tags: python, photo, metadata

Пишу проект для работы, нужно проверять дату и время фотографии которую мне присылают сотрудники в телеграмм.
Прочитал множество статей про метаданные EXIF(Знаю, что это не единственные)
Накидал такой код, чтобы проверить есть ли вообще такие метаданные в снимках, которые мне присылаю, но их там нет

```
from exif import Image
with open("./images/test1.jpg", "rb") as file:
image = Image(file)
if image.has_exif:
    status = f"contains EXIF (version {image.exif_version}) information."
else:
    status = "does not contain any EXIF information."
print(f"Image {status}")
```

Вывод консоли
*Image does not contain any EXIF information.*

Отсюда вопрос, реально ли это вообще сделать, или телеграмм подчищает все эти данные, так как считает их конфиденциальными

Возможно кто-то знает, как сделать через другой формат метаданных или использовать другой мессенджер, который не будет их подчищать(если да, то какой)?

Answer (score 0):

Получился такой код: он всегда выводит дату, тип изображения, его формат и т.д.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

imagename = "telegram_img.jpg"


image = Image.open(imagename)

info_dict = {
    "Filename": image.filename,
    "Image Size": image.size,
    "Image Height": image.height,
    "Image Width": image.width,
    "Image Format": image.format,
    "Image Mode": image.mode,
    "Image is Animated": getattr(image, "is_animated", False),
    "Frames in Image": getattr(image, "n_frames", 1)
}

for label,value in info_dict.items():
    print(f"{label:25}: {value}")
```